On a natural deduction rule concerning $\exists$ elimination
I wanted to see how a natural deduction proof system works, so I started reading these notes. On page four we find the following rule:

$$\frac{
\begin{matrix}
 & & \left[\phi[t/v]\right]\\
 & & \vdots\\
\exists v\phi & & \psi
\end{matrix}}
{\psi}$$
provided the constant $t$ does not
occur in $∃vφ$, or in $ψ$, or in any
undischarged assumption other
than $φ [t/v]$ in the proof of $ψ$.

Here is something I ponder, but which the notes don't seem to address:
Why is $t$ not allowed to appear in in any undischarged assumption?

As I understand it, the sentence $\phi[t/v]$ is in square brackets to mean that it is being assumed (without us knowing if it's true). This is called a discharged assumption. A more intuitive example of this is the following:
$$\frac{
\begin{matrix}
[\phi] & & [\phi]\\
\vdots & & \vdots\\
\psi & & \neg\psi
\end{matrix}}{\neg \phi}.$$

The reason is: we know that there is something that is $\phi$ and we call it $t$, but we have to avoid that $t$ has already a meaning, in which case it can be incompatible with being $\phi$.

Silly example from arithmetic: we prove that there is a number x greater than 1. What happens if we state "let call it 0"?

@MauroALLEGRANZA I see. Though wouldn't the rule allow us to call it "$0$" as long as $0$ does not appear in (certain) other sentences of the proof of $\psi$? Is the idea here that if $0$ does not appear in any undischarged sentence, then the proof could be carried out with another arbitrary constant $c$, and thus it's immaterial whether we use $0$ or $c$?

@MauroALLEGRANZA could we modify the rule so that the condition becomes "for a new term $t$ just added to the language"? I think that would guarantee that $t$ does not appear in any undischarged assumption, nor in $\exists v\phi$, nor in $\psi$ (since these are sentences of the language).

The issue is that 0 already occurs elsewhere: onto the axioms.
